# What is a back bearing when navigating with map and compass?

Tags: navigation, terminology, orienteering

Sometimes when navigating with map and compass one will take a **back bearing**, i.e. a **bearing taken directly opposite** to the direction one is travelling?

When and why would one want to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes **landmarks that you are travelling from, are much easier to take bearings to than what you are travelling towards**.

For example, in southern Utah near Bryce Canyon, there is a [cinder cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinder_cone) that rises several hundred vertical feet above a relatively flat forest. **Taking a bearing to the cinder cone is easy** since it rises well above the forest. Navigating **away is harder** since there aren't any landmarks in front of you to see.

However, it would be possible to t**ake a bearing from your position back to the cinder cone**, and thereby be able to tell **whether or not you are on course** or have strayed to the right or left of it.

It would look like this,

[image: back bearing with a compass]

As far as the calculations go, if you are **on course the back bearing should be 180 degrees to your direction of travel.** So if you had started out on a course of 270 degrees, then the back bearing should be 90 degrees.

Of course, you can also use the forward direction with your compass to navigate, but it can be **nice** to be able to take a back bearing in a situation like this and **confirm that you are on the same heading** as when you started.

Comment: A very similar technique is also useful when rowing a boat, since in that case you are facing the rear.  Essentially, you point the boat at your destination (looking over your shoulder), then observe a more convenient landmark in the opposite direction, which you then use for steering.